# Types of singularity that f may have at $0$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions, analytic-functions, singularity

Suppose f is holomorphic on a punctured neighborhood $D^*=\{z: 0<|z|<1\}$ and $f(z) \notin [0, \infty) \subset \mathbb{R}$ $ \forall z \in D^*.$ What are the possible types of singularity that f may have at $0$ (removable singularity, a pole or essential singularity)?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: *Hint:* Find a transformation $h$ such that $h(f(z))$ is *bounded* in $D^*$.

Comment: @Martin R Could you clarify your hint please? I still don’t understand how to solve the problem (without Picard’s theorem)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $G = \Bbb C \setminus [0, \infty)$. Let $\sqrt z$ be the analytic branch of the square root in $G$ which is determined by
$$
 \sqrt{re^{i \phi}} = \sqrt r e^{i \phi/2} \text{ with } 0 < \phi < 2 \pi \, .
$$
$\sqrt z$ maps $G$ conformally onto the upper halfplane, so that
$$
 h(z) = \frac{\sqrt z - i}{\sqrt z + i}
$$
maps $G$ conformally onto the unit disk.

It follows that $g = h \circ f$ is *bounded* in $D^*$, and therefore has a removable singularity at $z=0$.

Finally conclude that $f = h^{-1} \circ g$ also has a removable singularity at $z=0$.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**Few hints:**

- In any arbitrarily small nbd. of an *essential singularity* the function takes all complex values (*infinitely often*) with at most one possible exception.
- If $z_0$ is *pole* of $f(z)$ then $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}|f(z)|\rightarrow\infty$

Comment: could you help to prove the first statement?

Comment: @Irrik...its the statement of Picard's theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But can we prove that $0$ is not essential singularity without Picard's theorem?